# iCloud Drive not working after El Capitan upgrade, files not in com~apple~CloudDocs

Tags: icloud, macos

On one of my computers, iCloud Drive is not working after upgrading to El Capitan. The iCloud Drive folder is missing all my files in finder. Normally, these files are stored in `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/` for me locally. However, even this folder is empty. My iCloud Drive shows up fine on another one of my computers. I thought a fix may be to disable and reenable iCloud Drive in System Preferences, but when I do that I get the following message...

[image: iCloud Drive disable screenshot]

I have important files on iCloud Drive, so a cautiously click cancel. I have about 40 GB of files on it. I'm wondering if I should just be patient. I installed El Capitan two nights ago and need to access my files. I've been riddled with problems with iCloud Drive. After some misguided tinkering, many of my files take a ridiculously long time to load, but that's another thread. Does anyone know how I can safely get my iCloud Drive files back on my computer?

edit: In reponse to the first answer. `brctl log --wait --shorten` gives

`[note]    0.000 [2015-10-02 19:59:14.231] sqlite.clientTruth             sync-down.periodic-sync BRCPeriodicSyncOperation.m:137
    scheduled a useless periodic sync
[note]  717.386 [2015-10-02 20:11:11.617] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 0 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs
[note]  723.513 [2015-10-02 20:11:17.743] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 200 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs
[note]  2317.776 [2015-10-02 20:37:52.007] xpc.activity.com.apple.bird.configuration-server-update user-defaults           BRCUserDefaults.m:335
    downloading iCloud Drive configuration
[note]  2508.863 [2015-10-02 20:41:03.093] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 0 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs
[note]  2514.711 [2015-10-02 20:41:08.941] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 200 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs
[note]  4009.626 [2015-10-02 21:06:03.856] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 0 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs
[note]  4016.041 [2015-10-02 21:06:10.272] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 200 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs
[note]  5433.434 [2015-10-02 21:29:47.665] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 0 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs
[note]  5440.516 [2015-10-02 21:29:54.746] sqlite.serverTruth             zone.server               BRCServerZone.m:771
    received 200 edited items from the cloud for com.apple.CloudDocs`

Answer (score 1):

The first step is using `brctl log` from terminal to see what activity is happening and if you have errors.

- [How Do I Know If A File Has Been Successfully Synced To iCloud Drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151421/how-do-i-know-if-a-file-has-been-successfully-synced-to-icloud-drive/151810?s=1|0.6798#151810)

From there, you can be patient or call AppleCare or post a follow on question with some specifics on what's happening to your cloud sync.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I posted a short log above. I tried the iCloudStatus demo and it says "No files are being transferred".

Comment: I ended up just clicking "Delete from Mac" considering I have time machine backups of everything. After disabling and reenabling iCloud, the files showed up after about 24 hours. My performance in iCloud Drive is still slow, but at least I can see my files now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I relaunched Finder by pressing alt+rightclick on Finder icon and after the relaunch I clicked on Go in top bar and then iCloud Drive and it was fixed.
Hope it works for you as well.