# Is there a way via the command line to cause .icloud files to download?

Tags: terminal, icloud, command-line

Under iCloud in the Settings app, I have "Optimize Mac Storage" checked and "Desktop & Documents Folders" checked under "Apps that store documents and data in iCloud will appear here:"

[image]

This will cause some files in my "Documents" folder to be offloaded and replaced with a small file ending in ".icloud". I can download them by clicking on the cloud icon in the detail view in the Finder. I can also use "find" from the command line to show which files have been offloaded, eg "find . -name *.icloud | more".

Is there a command line way to cause these files to be downloaded, either by file or directory?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Scott Garret and Allan’s answer above is very close.

In the terminal, however, each `*.icloud` file is prefixed with a `.` when *NOT* downloaded.

For example, a directory called `foo` with optimised (i.e., offloaded to icloud) files `a.txt` and `b.txt` will look like this

```bash
$ cd foo
$ find . -name '.*icloud’
./.a.txt.icloud
./.b.txt.icloud
```

To resolve (i.e., download) the files from icloud, you need to pass the path to the *resulting* path to `/usr/bin/brctl`.

Thus, the following works.

```
find . -name '.*icloud' | perl -pe 's|(.*)/.(.*).icloud|$1/$2|s' | while read file; do brctl download "$file"; done
```

You can monitor the download activity as per [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151421/how-do-i-know-if-a-file-has-been-successfully-synced-to-icloud-drive) as follows :

```
brctl log -w --shorten
```

(There appears to be a bug where the full documented `--wait` flag isn't recognized.)

Comment: Slightly more robust and shorter: `find . -name '.*icloud' | sed 's|\.\([^/]*\)\.icloud$|\1|g' | while read fn; do brctl download "$fn"; done`

Comment: Here's another: `find . -type f -name "*.icloud" -exec brctl download {} \;`

Comment: For `brctl log --wait --shorten` I get `unrecognized option --wait`, but `-w` worked for me.

Comment: Interesting, @mpoisot. `man brctl` suggests both are possible, at least on Catalina.

Answer (score 18):

The command you are looking for is `brctl` (located in `/usr/bin`).  `man brctl` will tell you all you need, but basically just `brctl download /path/to/filename` (without the .icloud extension)  and `evict` will purge the locally cached copy.

Comment: Really nice!  I much prefer using built in utilities!  Oh...and Welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: Awesome to learn about `evict`! It boggles my mind why they don't expose this in Finder.

Comment: Nevermind. I see that MacOS Catalina added this to Finder. Also it looks like `evict` no longer works on the command line (?). I get an `Operation not supported` error.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, `brctl download` is asynchronous (just like when executed using the GUI).

Answer (score 8):

To my knowledge, there is no command included that allows you to directly download an iCloud file or folder.

But since I had exactly the same problem as you, I found that it was possible to do it in Swift with the [startDownloadingUbiquitousItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410377-startdownloadingubiquitousitem) function.

So I wrote a really simple Swift script for downloading both folder and file. You can download it on Github: [iCloud Downloader](https://github.com/farnots/iCloudDownloader)

I hope I have answered your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the iCloud files were in a Mobile Documents directory. So to cut short time there, I focused the script just to that. Also fixed the issues based on comments from members above.

This is my icloudforcesync.sh file content (make sure you apply `chmod +x icloudforcesync.sh` to make it exeutable):

```bash
#/bin/bash

icloudDir="~/Library/Mobile Documents/"
 
find "${icloudDir}" -name '.*icloud' | perl -pe 's|(.*)/.(.*).icloud|$1/$2|s' | while read file; do brctl download "$file"; done

brctl log -w -t
```

Do comment if there's more improvements that can be introduced to this or if there are other better ways.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387727/9058 ?