# How to examine my iPhone WhatsApp iCloud backup from my Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

I read the thread [Accessing WhatsApp iCloud backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365950/accessing-whatsapp-icloud-backup) and did all Kanthala Raghu explained to reveal iCloud WhatsApp backup in the terminal. But what I get is only a list in the terminal after typing `cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/find *whatsapp*`. Like these:

- `57TXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp`
- `57TXXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/Documents`

Now I can only see they exist on the terminal console. How can I examine the files or content stored in the backup?

Comment: The answer you indicate also says how to download and untar the files.  What happens after you do that step?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to terminal command. After typing "cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/find whatsapp" I only see these 2 things: -57TXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp -57TXXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/Documents (I put XXX instead of numbers) I can't see any .tar

Answer (score 1):

The files are already downloaded to your Mac. The folder you're searching is on your local Mac.

As explained in the answer you've linked, the backups are stored as `tar` archives (`tar` being a program that can bundle multiple files in one archive file). You can do as they instruct:

```
cp *whatsapp*/Accounts/*/backup/*.tar ~/AFolderIChoose
```

Create the "AFolderIChoose" folder in your home directory before running the command. You should then see that folder populated with the backup archives. You can double them in Finder to unpack them.

Comment: I just created a folder at the first level of my home folder (the user folder). Typed cp *whatsapp*/Accounts/*/backup/*.tar ~/AFolderIChoose (With the right name of my folder) but I get this: cp: *whatsapp*/Accounts/*/backup/*.tar: No such file or directory :(( Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ted525 You have the command text wrong; you're missing `*` before the `tar` command.  You have to follow the command exactly.

Comment: I typed cp *whatsapp*/Accounts/*/backup/*.tar ~/GoodFolder (which is the name of my folder). But I get this: cp: *whatsapp*/Accounts/*/backup/*.tar: No such file or directory. As I said above I After typing "cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/find whatsapp" I only see these 2 things: -57TXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp -57TXXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/Documents (I put XXX instead of numbers). Does it means the backup are existing or maybe not ? You can't imagine how much finding those backup are important for me. I thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Copy the command _exactly_ as written. The * you missed before .tar makes the difference between a command that works, and one that does nothing at all.

Comment: I did put the * in terminal. I copy and paste the command, just replacing the name of my folder. I also checked the spaces between letters. The* don't show up in my messages ! don't know why because I also cut and pasted, they do appear on terminal. I'm trying again and again with no luck.I only see in the list 2 lines. Are the .tar inside those folders ? : -57TXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp -57TXXXXXX~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/Documents. Then type: cp *whatsapp*/Accounts/*/backup/*.tar ~/NameOfMyFolder  and I get :
No such file or directory .I also tried to search using EasyFind but nothing...

Comment: If you haven’t got a tar file in those folders, you haven’t got a backup.

Comment: I can't even find those 2 folders. I just see them in terminal list but no way to reveal them in finder. After the command in terminal you gave me or after serching for hidden files. Anyway I loste hope because what I need is a backup from the 9 of june. And I don't know if a daily backup replace the last one. Backup was set to daily... So even I find those .tar not sure what I will find the right ones. I saw that on android backup are stored for several months. look at 3'12 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPivkTW6Uts (it's in french but you can see the backups files)

Comment: You can use the command "open ." to open the current folder in Finder. So cd to the indicated path and use that command to browse it in Finder. You could also browse iCloud Drive normally in Finder and find the WhatsApp folder.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, did I do everything right?                                         cd /Users/user/Library/Mobile\ Documents                                                                          mkdir ~/AFolderIChoose; cp *whatsapp*/Accounts/*/backup/*.tar ~/AFolderIChoose

Answer (score -1):

Another way is restore the backup directly on iphone.

Comment: Question asks ‘how do I download them to my Mac?’