# How many whatsapp backup are stored on icloud?

Tags: icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

I erased a very important whatsapp discussion 6 days ago and I'd like to get it back. The problem is auto-backup on my Iphone 8 is set to "daily". So when i erase the app from iphone and restore from icloud the backup I get is the last one. Does Icloud keep older whatsapp backup somewhere ? and how could I get them and replace the newest ?
Thanks !

Comment: Just for future info, if the backup is important then keep your own copy and don't rely on auto-backup...

Comment: See this relevant  question/answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365950/119271

Comment: Yes I've already read it and I've tried the command in terminal, I got a backup files list but I don't know how to dowload those files. Please can you check this question I've posted here ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393915/how-to-download-whatsapp-icloud-backup