# Find Whatsapp backup

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, big-sur, whatsapp.app

If I create a WhatsApp Chat backup on my iPhone and save it on iCloud, how can I find it again?

I couldn't find it on my Mac via iCloud Drive or on icloud.com. Where exactly does WhatsApp save this backup?

Comment: Your question says "If I create a WhatsApp chat backup...", does that mean you haven't created one yet and are asking where it would be?  Or are you saying that you actually did create a backup and now you can't find it?  Your question is a bit confusing the way it's currently written.

Comment: Yes, I have already made several Whatsapp backups, but unfortunately I can't find them.

Comment: There's dozens of 'WhatsApp backup' questions that have accepted answers, like [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365950/88313).  I know you said you can't find it but how you looked for it is very vague.  Have you tried the answers already provided?

Comment: I could find the 82G3428HV4~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp on my MAC but I am not sure how to look into it. Can you share the details? iCloud says that 1.5GB is used by WhatsApp but this file is quite small. I am not sure where all the data is stored. I want to download this on my MAC (WhatsApp chats/pictures etc.). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would very much like to answer my question myself, now that I have become a little smarter on this subject. Maybe I can help one or the other even if it's just one.

My problem was, I made a WhatsApp backup on the ICloud, but couldn't find it on my Mac `iCloud Drive` or on `icloud.com`, so it was really strange.

Until I discovered that ICloud Drive doesn't show me all things, for example with the Finder. I was able to find these hidden files using the terminal.

First you switch to the directory

```
cd /Users/$(stat -f %Su)/Library/Mobile\ Documents
```

The `ls` command can be used to find things that the Finder cannot find.

To show more hidden files `ls -a`, but in my case `ls` was sufficient

Then

```
     ls |grep whatsapp

     82G3428HV4~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp
```

We can, for example, copy this into the home directory to look at it

```
cp -rf "82G3428HV4~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp" ~/whatsapp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the WhatsApp backup as a file and only the latest backup is maintained. You can see its size in `Manage Storage` on `iCloud`. When you reinstall WhatsApp on the same or new iPhone, it will prompt you if you want to restore from iCloud backup.