# Accessing a Whatsapp backup on iCloud Drive (Windows)

Tags: icloud, backup, windows, whatsapp.app

I am trying to retrieve a Whatsapp backup file that is stored on iCloud. I have found this thread which explains how to do that with a Macbook: [accessing whatsapp icloud backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365950/accessing-whatsapp-icloud-backup?newreg=c06b148c130e4038bfdcb57af31c1b97)

I have a pc with Windows 10 so I installed iCloud drive on it, then tried to look for any hidden files from the command line, but I cannot find anything (used dir /a:h). When I click on the storage button in the icloud window, I can see there is 186MB for Whatsapp, which I think corresponds to the backup I am looking for.

Any advice on how I could access that Whatsapp backup file? Ultimately, I am trying to download the file, then will try to use a third-party software to try to load back in a new phone.

Thanks!