# How can I find WhatsApp backup data stored in iCloud?

Tags: icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

Following instructions from previous questions have not helped (more below).

I have lost access to my previous phone. I don't have access to any iOS device. I'm trying to recover any WhatsApp message data I might have backed up on iCloud.

In my Mac, when I go on
Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > Manage...
and select WhatsApp, I get this, which says I have 2GB in my iCloud Storage:

[image: Menu on Mac says WhatsApp Messenger with 2GB written below it.]

In order to locate those 2GB, I disabled Mac Storage Optimization, went into "Library/Mobile Data" via terminal and searched up for WhatsApp files using:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/
find *whatsapp*
```

The only three results were:

```
57T9237FN3~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp
57T9237FN3~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/.DS_Store
57T9237FN3~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/Documents
```

Navigating into those via terminal, ls -a returns nothing besides what's above.

I would have just concluded that dumb me turned off backup at some point to save storage, but then why does it say in settings that there is a 2 GB backup attributed to WhatsApp? Could it be somewhere else?

Most of the instructions I've followed come from this thread:
[Accessing WhatsApp iCloud backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365950/accessing-whatsapp-icloud-backup)
However, most go from the find terminal command finding actually .tar files and such, which wasn't my case.