# Accessing whatsapp backup on macbook

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, whatsapp.app

I am trying to access my whatsapp backup from icloud on macbook. I read and did all the steps mentioned in this post: [Accessing WhatsApp iCloud backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365950/accessing-whatsapp-icloud-backup) but it didn't work me. I can see my whatsapp backup(3.2GB) on icloud drive and even after turning on icloud drive on macbook and disabling optimize mac storage option the whatsapp folder is completely empty.
Am I missing something ?
[image]