# Accessing Time Machine Backup of WhatsApp Mac iCloud backup folder

Tags: terminal, icloud, backup, time-machine, whatsapp.app

I previously found this thread looking at [accessing WhatsApp's iCloud backup on the Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365950/accessing-whatsapp-icloud-backup) and managed to access those files using Terminal.

I was trying to find my Time Machine backup of these synchronised files. I was wondering if anyone knew how I could use Terminal to access the Time Machine backups of the files in those directories?

Thanks ahead.