# How to download iCloud library (Backup folder, e.g WhatsApp) to Desktop (Mac)

Tags: icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

How can I download folders from ~/Library/Mobile Documents/ ?

- I see that I have 10 gigabyte of files saved in the cloud as WhatsApp backup.
- I want to download that to my desktop.
- I know it is located in e.g. /Library/Mobile Documents/42T9237FN3~net~whatsapp~WhatsApp/Accounts/<98798799897>/backup

But I can only see meta files of type .icloud there on desktop.

I need to fetch the whole folder and all backup files to my desktop for further investigation.

Any idea?

Comment: Can't you download it from www.icloud.com ?

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379643/9058) might also help

Comment: @sfxedit no, cannot download it from the website, because that folder is not visible there (it is part of the pretty much hidden Library).

Comment: @nohillside sounds interesting, will look into that... It's all quite complicated...

Comment: Also this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328329/is-there-a-way-via-the-command-line-to-cause-icloud-files-to-download