# Terminal command to play sound file from iCloud drive

Tags: terminal, icloud

if i run a terminal command to play a sound from a local drive, such as `afplay /Users/username/Music/file.aiff` it plays.

However, if I try the same thing with a file on iCloud it will not:  `afplay /Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sounds/file.aiff`

And outputs this:

```
Options: (may appear before or after arguments)
  {-v | --volume} VOLUME
    set the volume for playback of the file
  {-h | --help}
    print help
  { --leaks}
    run leaks analysis
  {-t | --time} TIME
    play for TIME seconds
  {-r | --rate} RATE
    play at playback rate
  {-q | --rQuality} QUALITY
    set the quality used for rate-scaled playback (default is 0 - low quality, 1 - high quality)
  {-d | --debug}
    debug print output
```

any advice?

Comment: Path looks wrong. I don't use iCloud Drive at all so I can't check, but see https://osxdaily.com/2017/11/16/access-icloud-drive-command-line-mac/ Might be as simple as escaping the space with `\ `

Comment: I probably forgot how often I posted an answer to similar questions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any shell command, you need to escape the space in the path name:

```
afplay ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sounds/file.aiff
```

You also need to make sure that the file to be played is actually downloaded from iCloud. [Is there a way via the command line to cause .icloud files to download?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328329/is-there-a-way-via-the-command-line-to-cause-icloud-files-to-download) has some answers on how to accomplish this.