# iCloud Sync activity log

Tags: terminal, icloud, logs, activity-monitor, console

Trying to figure out how to see activity happening while iCloud Files is syncing. The macOS Console application shows messages from `cloudd`, but nothing very useful:

[image]

The Activity Monitor does not show `cloudd` nor other process transferring much data either.

I'm looking for log files under `/var/log` or `~/Library/Logs`, but cannot find anything.

Is there any log file that could be used with `tail` to see iCloud sync activity in real time?

Comment: Here is the main q&a for this topic https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151421/how-do-i-know-if-a-file-has-been-successfully-synced-to-icloud-drive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `brctl` like `brctl log --wait`. When it stops showing messages it's synced.

There seems to be a lot of options and little information. [This blog post](http://www.mackungfu.org/knowing-if-icloud-drive-is-syncing) might be helpful

Comment: As far as 2020 and MacOS Catalina --wait parameter no longer exists.

Comment: You can use brctl `log -w --shorten` on Catalina